# crazy issue to display 2 variables in echo with bash/shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a stupid problem completely crazy with shell/bash script.
I have a configuration file with 2 variables defined...See below my file called **test.conf** :

```
WEB_DIR="www"
TPL_DIR="tpl"
```

Now I have my shell/bash script called **test.sh** with this content :

```
#!/bin/bash
source test.conf
echo $WEB_DIR
echo $TPL_DIR
echo -e "$WEB_DIR - $TPL_DIR"
exit 0
```

As you can seen this is very simple because this kind of script should return this :

```
www
tpl
www - tpl
```

But, I don't know why, when I launch this script, he returns this :

```
www
tpl
- tpl
```

We can see that the first variable **$WEB_DIR** is missing and I don't know why because she is defined.

Do you have an idea why?

Thanks
L.

Comment: Check your file for DOS style carriage returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test.conf` has DOS line endings, so the value of each variable ends with a carriage return. Compare:

```
$ WEB_DIR=$'www\r'
$ TPL_DIR=$'tpl\r'
$ echo -e "$WEB_DIR - $TPL_DIR"
 - tpl
```

The carriage return at the end of `WEB_DIR` is "displayed" by moving the cursor to the beginning of the line, so that `- tpl` overwrites `www`.

Remove the DOS line endings with `dos2unix`, or use your text editor to save the file using Unix line endings.